# Export house to Unity

Tags: export, texture-baking

I made this simple house for a game i'm making in Unity but I'm not sure about how to export it.[image]

I know I can bake it but when I bake it the progression bar is stuck at 0% and I don't think baking will work with glass. What should I do ?

Comment: If you want to bake the texture, you can decrease the render samples to 1 what makes the baking much faster. You have to assign a different material to the windows and create a transparent shader for it in Unity.

Comment: What resolution should I put ?

Comment: If it textured inside-outside at least 4096p.